# Apply Resource_Groups to specific schedules?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We're having an issue within our Gitlab instance that runs test jobs.  We have approximately 30 scheduled jobs, which are either triggered manually or by the API.  out of those jobs, about 10 are specific to a ci/cd pipeline, and they get triggered all the time by merges/commits.  What we'd like to do is use resource_group, but only apply that setting to those specific jobs.

when I add "resource_group: runtest" to our yml file, it applies to ALL our scheduled pipelines.  Is there a way to apply it to just a specific set of schedules?  Maybe by using a tag or specifc naming convention?

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to create extra jobs in your GitLab config so that you have some with `resource_group` and some without and then choose which to include in the pipeline using an environment variable input when the pipeline is triggered.

```
job with resource group:
  script: echo "Hello!"
  rules:
    - if: $MY_VARIABLE = "ThisIsASchedule" 
      when: always
  resource_group: production

job without resource group:
  script: echo "Hello!"
  rules:
    - if: $MY_VARIABLE != "ThisIsASchedule" 
      when: never
```

Comment: That seems like it would then NOT run the jobs without the variable, which is not what I'm after.  I want all the other jobs to run as concurrently as normal, but the others with the variable set be under the resource_group setting.

Comment: i also tried and if / then in the job itself, 

    if [[ "$CORE" == "True" ]] then resource_group: core  
but that also complains about a syntax error.  

If I just add "resource_group: core" in the job section , that works fine, but applies to ALL schedules running that job.

Comment: Thanks for the direction,   figured it out.  Posted below for others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the direction Glen Thomas.   Was able to get it to work.

had to refactor our gitlab-ci.yml file a bit to organize it better,  now have two jobs that run the tests.   One checks to see if the variable is false, and if so, runs the jobs as normal.  the 2nd job checks if the variable is true, and if so, runs the jobs, but with the added resource_group setting so those jobs wait for the previous job to finish before kicking off .

so:

job1 :
script: echo "regular schedules"

- if: $Variable != "True"
  do all the test things here;

job2:
script echo "group schedules"

- if: $Variable == "True"
  resource_group: group
  do all the test things here